# How do I change an object based on Camera rotation in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm trying to make a 2D sprite flip in a 3D scene, whenever the camera reaches an Y rotation of 180.

I can't get it to work, even though the TEST debug text shows whenever it reaches 180.

This is the code I have:

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotate_enemy : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

public bool flipX;


void Update()
{
    float fYRot = Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.y;


    if (fYRot >= 180)
    {
        Debug.Log("TESTING");
        spriteRenderer.flipX = true;
    }
    else
    {
        spriteRenderer.flipX = false;
    }
 }
}
```

I have a similiar script, that instead changes rotation based on velocity (the direction to which the character is going), and that script works just fine.

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

public class Sprite_flip : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer; 

public bool flipX;


Vector3 pos, velocity;

void Awake()
{
    pos = transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    velocity = (transform.position - pos) / Time.deltaTime;
    pos = transform.position;

    if (velocity.x >= 0)
    {
        spriteRenderer.flipX = true;
    }
    else
    {
        spriteRenderer.flipX = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone who might have an idea why the Rotate_Enemy script isn't doing what I want to achieve? Tried to find solutions but I couldn't make any of them work, so there must be something I don't understand. Super grateful for any help! :)

Comment: The `Rotate_enemy` works fine for me. Are you maybe using a different SpriteRenderer then you are expecting? Maybe make the `SpriteRenderer` public and see if it's the correct one.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for trying! I am confident I'm using the correct SpriteRenderer, since there are only 2 in the whole project. The other one being a cast shadow. I tried making it public but that made no difference. 

So you're saying it works for you in Unity? Is it a 2D or 3D scene? And do you have a perspective or ortographic camera? I'm having a 3D scene with an ortographic camera.

Comment: Add another debug statement to the other condition. Euler angles are funny things and I would be you're seeing a wrap of some kind - you're probably doing something like going to +181 degrees, but Unity is reporting it as -179 degrees, and you're flipping it immediately around.

Comment: It seems like the problem lied within the Sprite_flip script, or rather due to the fact that they both co-existed.  I'm not sure exactly why, I'm quite tired atm, but I guess that they both were changing the same boolean and for some reason that didn't work.

When I disabled the Sprite_flip script, Rotate_enemy worked. So instead, I put them both in the same script. Which seems to work fine so far. Thanks for your answers! I'm sure they will be useful in the future if/when I find any new bugs.